# Python: variables scope and profile.run

Tags: python, variables, scope, profile

I want to call profile.run within my function, i.e.:

```
def g():
    ...
def f():
    x = ...
    run.profile('g(x)')
```

However, it says 'x is not defined' when calling run.profile. As far as I understand, I have to supply import statement before calling g(x) inside string argument to run.profile, and I could do this with global variables.

Is this possible with local variables?

Comment: Please show the unabridged code and the specific error or traceback.

Comment: Reduced version of my code that shows the problem:
`import profile
def g(x):
    pass
def f():
    x = 0
    profile.run('g(x)')

f()`

However, it shows "NameError: name 'g' is not defined".

Anyway, it is the same problem and profile.runctx solves the problem. Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 22):

Instead of using `run()` use `runctx()` which allows you to supply locals and globals. For example:

```
>>> import cProfile
>>> def g(x):
...   print "g(%d)" % x
... 
>>> x=100
>>> cProfile.runctx('g(x)', {'x': x, 'g': g}, {})
g(100)
         3 function calls in 0.000 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <stdin>:1(g)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

>>>
```

See also `runctx()` in [this document](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having `x` set to the arguments to the function, have `x` include the entire function call.

Example:

```
import cProfile
def g(x):
    print x
x = """g("Hello world!")"""
cProfile.run(x)
```